# Show more or less text with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need to create a 'basic' show more, show less text toggle using JavaScript and HTML. I have found plenty of examples; however, it must allow for 'graceful degradation' so that, when JavaScript is turned off or not available, the 'hidden' text is displayed.
As much as I would love to use jQuery, this isn't an option.

Any examples would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: As far as graceful degradation, the easiest would be to show the whole thing upfront, then immediately run the "show less" function (assuming JS is on) when the page loads.

Answer (score 1):

I would do a mix of CSS and minor JavaScript.

```
text-overflow:ellipsis;
```

will output something like

`This is my text and it is...`

when the text is too large for its surrounding element. Then when the page loads, just shrink the element to make it smaller and have a "read more" button next to it that will trigger a JS function that will grow the element to the full size.

Comment: yes if you are allowed CSS3 this is a good way. I have to support back to IE7 so I think in the old ways...

Comment: Won't matter, you just won't get the ellipsis on older browsers, the "read more" button will still show. This is just a minor aesthetic that makes things look better. Similar to how rounded corners on elements can look nice, you would still do it for people using recent browsers. You wouldn't keep it out just because some people can't see it.

Comment: yeah fair enough, i guess i've never thought about it because i've only looked at server-side truncates never the js way. The only issue I can think of with doing it by element height is that maybe it is inlined with some images or something? That's kindof a silly edge case tho

Answer (score 0):

you can just have it load the full text by default, then have a javascript method that truncates it... and keep the full text stored (in js var or better probably hidden in the page) to restore

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onclick="hide('hide1')">Show/Hide text</button>
<span id="hide1" class="hide">This is extra text</span>


<script>
var hideElements = document.getElementsByClassName("hide");
for (i=0; i<hideElements.length; i++) {
hideElements[i].style.display = "none";
}
function hide(elem) {
var hideElement = document.getElementById(elem);
if (hideElement.style.display == "inline-block") {
hideElement.style.display = "none";
} else {
hideElement.style.display = "inline-block";
}
}
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/weissman258/N5e3N/